# Sorting Headers

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have an `NSTable` populated with data. I have sorted the columns using the following code. The problem is that it sorts the Number column alphabetically when I want it numerically.

```
(1,100,101,2,20,21,3,30,31................)
```

I have the data entered as numbers `(@1, @2, @3)` and not strings `(@"1", @"2", @"3")`

```
// THIS WILL SORT ALL COLUMNS //

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn:(NSTableColumn     *)tableColumn

{

NSTableColumn *NumberColumn = [tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"No."];
NSSortDescriptor *NumberSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"No."
                                    ascending:YES
                                    selector:@selector(compare:)];
[NumberColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:NumberSortDescriptor];

NSTableColumn *CardNameColumn = [tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"Card Name"];
NSSortDescriptor *CardNameSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                      sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Card Name"
                                      ascending:YES
                                      selector:@selector(compare:)];
[CardNameColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:CardNameSortDescriptor];

NSTableColumn *TypeColumn = [tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"Type"];
NSSortDescriptor *TypeSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Type"
                                    ascending:YES
                                    selector:@selector(compare:)];
[TypeColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:TypeSortDescriptor];

NSTableColumn *RarityColumn = [tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"Rarity"];
NSSortDescriptor *RaritySortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                      sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Rarity"
                                      ascending:YES
                                      selector:@selector(compare:)];
[RarityColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:RaritySortDescriptor];

NSTableColumn *UnlimitedColumn = [tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"Unlimited"];
NSSortDescriptor *UnlimitedSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                      sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Unlimited"
                                      ascending:YES
                                      selector:@selector(compare:)];
[UnlimitedColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:UnlimitedSortDescriptor];

NSTableColumn *FirstEditionColumn = [tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"1st Edition"];
NSSortDescriptor *FirstEditionSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                      sortDescriptorWithKey:@"1st Edition"
                                      ascending:YES
                                      selector:@selector(compare:)];
[FirstEditionColumn setSortDescriptorPrototype:FirstEditionSortDescriptor];

}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView sortDescriptorsDidChange:(NSArray
                                                             *)oldDescriptors
{
[BaseSet sortUsingDescriptors: [tableView sortDescriptors]];
[tableView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that all of my code was correct here. The problem was that my app was saving my array on termination and it had saved it before i had turned the strings into numbers.